# Is there any multiple-inheritance code in the C++ standard library or in Boost?

Tags: boost, multiple-inheritance, std

Is there any code in the:

1. C++ standard library (as of C++14, or in the final draft of C++17)
2. Boost libraries

that uses multiple inheritance?

(I'm interested in this fact in the context of forming a mental picture of where multiple inheritance "stands" in the C++ world these days.)

Comment: `<iostream>` comes to mind. But all in all I believe the C++ standard library uses polymorphism (multiple inheritance or single inheritance) very seldomly.

Comment: Multiple inheritance is used extensively in internal implementation code in both Boost and the major STLs, specifically in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern where your subclass is a CRTP generated refinement of some base class. Some of the tuple like containers do fun stuff like inherit from everything in a variadic template parameter list etc.

Comment: But what Boost and very little of any STL does is use *virtual multiple inheritance* for lots of very good reasons. Indeed, virtual inheritance in anything is a big red flag pointing towards bad design, and it is overwhelmingly avoided by anyone competent in any new C++ written in the past decade.

Comment: @NiallDouglas: I was more interested in outwards-facing code, but - can you link to the example you just gave?